# Adding ?Source to Infopath Link in SPD Workflow Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath, email, tasks

I have a workflow which sends task emails to users and I've updated the "Related Item" link so that it opens directly to the Item ([Server Relative URL]). I would like to append `?source=RedirectURL` to the end of the link so that after submitting the Form, they would go to a page reminding them to complete their task.

Currently in the email that is going out, the User can hover the link and see the url including `?source=RedirectURL`, but when the link is clicked, the Infopath form opens without the `?source=RedirectURL` portion.

Does anyone know of a way to get this url ending to stick?